# BigQuery API query usage per day always at 0

Tags: google-cloud-platform

In the Google cloud console, under "Quotas" page, I set a custom quota (300Tb) for "BigQuery API query usage per day".

Despite the daily use (via java library, python library or the via BigQuery console) I see the used quota is always at 0.

Does the "Quotas" page show the Tb used?
Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: To check your used quota in a region, run:  `gcloud compute regions describe example-region` and To check the available quota for resources in your project `gcloud compute project-info describe --project myproject`

Comment: Using gcloud compute project-info describe --project myproject i see some limit and metrics but none of them are related to BigQuery. My question is: does the "Quotas" page show the Tb used?

Comment: Please check this one. - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20512847/how-can-i-see-the-currently-reached-used-quota-in-bq

Answer (score 0):

You can find the BigQuery API - Query usage per day quota consumption levels in the console's [IAM & Admin --> Quotas page](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas) where it will show the current usage percentage and a 7 day peak usage percentage.

Another option would be to check the [Monitoring tool](https://console.cloud.google.com/monitoring/metrics-explorer) for the [Scanned bytes billed metric](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/monitoring-dashboard#create-alert).